# Can multi target framework(4.0 and 2.0) projects be present in vS2010, if so what are the risks? Is it safe and no harm in it

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2010

Recently we upgraded to from VS2005 to VS 2010. Solution is Its a mixture of C sharp and VC++ projects.

All c-sharp projects are targeted to .Net Frameowrk 4.0.

Recently we came across a problem that, one C# project(Name X) has references to SQL  server (Replication.dll ) dlls and SQL server dlls are of runtime version v2.0.50727. we Faced an issue because of this.
So we changed this C # project target FRamework to 2.0 . And the issue we were facing is resolved.

My question is , how safe is it to have projects in VS 2010 both .net framework 4.0 and 2.0.
Only one project we changed to .Net framework 2.0 . Rest are in 4.0

Is it safe ? No harm in having this configuration? Any risks here?

Note: And yes, others projects(targeting 4.0) have dependency on this project X(targeting 2.0). Other projects do call method/functions of X project.

Comment: You can get the newer version of those dlls that supports .net framework 4

Comment: It's totally safe but as suggested by ElectricRogue you should reference the newer version of those dlls

Comment: I understand, my 1st approach was that to get the new versions. I took DLLs from SQL server 2012 and referenced in the project X. But I see the properties( as seen in VS2010) of the SQL server dll, is yet showing runtime version v2.0.50727

Comment: And the issue we faced was when I access a method of project x, I would get the below error     CLR:(C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication\10.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.dll)
 ERR: Rejecting IJW module built against v2.0.50727 because it could be loaded
 into another runtime in this process